# How access session data (of node-client-sessions) on socket.io?

Tags: node.js, session, express, socket.io

Session data in my app is handled with [node-client-sessions](https://npmjs.org/package/client-sessions) (as suggested in [Using secure client-side sessions to build simple and scalable Node.JS applications](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/12/using-secure-client-side-sessions-to-build-simple-and-scalable-node-js-applications-a-node-js-holiday-season-part-3/)) and now I have [socket.io](https://npmjs.org/package/socket.io) (websockets) to handle some real-time features. I would like to authenticate logged in users by their session data on handshake. But socket.io, on handshake, gives us this [`handshakeData`](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing#handshaking) object and it doesn't expose the request object completely. I need to access the session property of the request. Any ideas?

I'm using [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/) (nodejs).

**UPDATE**

Inspired @LaurentPerrin's answer I dove into client-sessions source and found out decode and encode functions exposed. Perhaps not as easy as mess with my session object directly, but very effective so far.

My code, so far:

```
/*jslint node: true, es5: true, nomen: true, unparam: true */

'use strict';

var encode = require('client-sessions').util.encode,
    decode = require('client-sessions').util.decode,
    cookie = require('cookie'),

    cookieSettings = require('./persistors/cookieSettings'),

    authorized = {
        'me@domain.com': 1
    };

module.exports = function websocket(io) {
    io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback) {
        var session_data;
        if (!handshakeData.headers.cookie) {
            callback({
                status: 'forbidden',
                reason: 'no session',
                source: 'socket_io'
            }, false);
            return;
        }
        session_data = decode(cookieSettings, cookie.parse(handshakeData.headers.cookie).session).content;
        if (authorized[session_data.email]) {
            handshakeData.session_data = session_data;
            callback(null, true);
        } else {
            // callback({
            //     status: 'forbidden',
            //     reason: 'unauthorized',
            //     source: 'socket_io'
            // }, false);
            callback(null, false);
        }
        return;
    });
    io.set('transports', ['websocket', 'flashsocket']);
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log('connected')
        socket.on('credenciamento', function (data) {
            console.log(socket.handshake.session_data.email);
            socket.broadcast.emit('credenciamento', {
                inscrito_id: data.inscrito_id
            });
        });
    });
};
```

It's by no means complete. But the authorization parts seems to be working just fine. =)

Now, about the callback function. At first I used it like @LaurentPerrin, passing an object with the false response. But it generates a warning. Socket.io considers that an error ocurred:

`warn  - handshake error [object Object]`

So in the second moment I passed `null` as first parameter when not authorizing:

`info  - handshake unauthorized`

Considering the way socket.io understands each thing, the second way seems to be more correct semantically. =)

I choose the second way. Pick one yourself.

Comment: thank you for the info about the exposed encode/decode methods! I was wondering if you got client-sessions fully to work with sockets or not? I am asking since there doesn't seem to be a possibility to update the cookie (with the session info within) when changing the session object within a socket event on the backend. I could switch to LongPolling but would loose the benefits of sockets or I could use a Redis Backend for the sessions but would loose the benefit of client-sessions. Any clue?

Comment: @japrescott I just needed authorization so I don't think I did more than just authorization. But can't you modify the "cookie" and encode it again? I would think it would work... Well, let me know! And I'll check my code. It's an old project now...
Anyway, you might still need Redis, remember:

"Immediate revocation of Persona sessions
One of the main downsides of client-side sessions as compared to server-side ones is that the server no longer has the ability to destroy sessions."

Comment: my solution now consists of using cookiesession to store the userid so i can detect the user forever in the future. once 'authorized' with db hit, user data is stored in redis for later user-info/session retrieval. further requests can be trusted from there on and dont need a db hit to validate the user and I can grab from redis directly and trust its that user calling. But the man-in-the-middle attack vector remains, but could be closed with ssl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it's exactly the same thing, but I wrote this in my case. Note that I require directly in express dependencies to avoid version problems.

```
var cookie = require('express/node_modules/cookie'),
    parseSignedCookie = require('express/node_modules/connect').utils.parseSignedCookie,
    parseJSONCookie = require('express/node_modules/connect').utils.parseJSONCookie;

…

io.set('authorization', authorizeSocket);

…

function authorizeSocket(handshake, done) {
  if (!handshake.headers.cookie)
    return done({status: 'forbidden', reason: 'no session', source: 'socket_io'}, false);

  var cookies = cookie.parse(handshake.headers.cookie),
      signed = cookies['your_session_cookie'];

  if (!signed)
    return done({status: 'forbidden', reason: 'tampered cookie', source: 'socket_io'}, false);

  var raw = parseSignedCookie(signed, 'your_session_secret'),
  json = parseJSONCookie(raw);

  if (!json || !json.passport || !json.passport.user)
    return done({status: 'forbidden', reason: 'bad session', source: 'socket_io'}, false);

  // finally...
  var user = json.passport.user;

  handshake.user = user;

  done(null, true);
}
```

Comment: I think a get the idea. But does it work with client-sessions? I mean, it doesn't seem to expose a way to decrypt the session data in the cookie by ourselves. There is this session object (and it's great) accessible in every request (and just a little too far from my reach using socket.io...).

Comment: Or perhaps it does! Your answer was an inspiration to move on! Thank you very much! (I still would like to have access to the session object, it's so close! =P)

Comment: One last time, thanks. I'm doing it mostly the way you showed me. It seems it's even easier using `client-sessions`. I updated my answer with some code and considerations.
What may be of interest to you is: passing an object as first parameter for your done function implies there was an error in the authorization process. Semantics... Is it not authorizing an error? Socket.io messages made me think not.